# How to run php with sql server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am creating an android application that uses PHP and SQL Server 2008. I have successfully connected these with the help of Wampserver on my machine and Sql Server on remote location.
The problem is now I don’t know where to run PHP webservice so that I can access PHP webservice remotely at all times through my android application.

I tried using the hosting site www.bytehost32.com but it didn’t work.
I also tried to install PHP on IIS and run on same server as the database but could not find an appropriate solution that suits my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think 000webhost.com id quite easy to setup and reliable (and free). (If you're interested .tk domain registration is free).

Comment: I have a solution in mind. Plz suggest if it is correct way to proceed. I have an application server. If I install wampserver on it and store my php file in the www directory and access php through the IP address of that server, Will it work ??

Comment: The thing is that Wamp is intended for local use and it just basically a bundle of preconfigured software (Apache, Mysql). I have never run a live webserver but I don't think using Wamp for live webserver purpuses is a good idea. If you are planning to host it on a plain server you have to install Apache, but if you use a webhost service website (like 000webhost) they have Apache, MySql and some other stuff preinstalled and mostly configured.

Comment: I tried using 000webhost.com also. It doesnt seem to work. I didnt get any response from running it. No idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of PHP you're using, but if you're using PHP5+ you can use Microsoft's SQL Server Driver for PHP. 
Use this link :http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/

Make sure you use version 2, which gives you the PDO functionality as well as the procedural style.

Comment: I have connected Sql server with php and android successfully. The only thing is in that case php is on my local machine so my android application device has to be in the same network as the wampserver. What I want is to store php somewhere from where I can access it remotely at all times and there is no limitation of being on the same network.